# Does shell confuse <space> with <new line> when reading text files?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, ubuntu-11.04

i tried to run this script :

```
for line in $(cat song.txt)
do echo "$line" >> out.txt
done
```

running it on ubuntu 11.04

when "song.txt" contains :

```
I read the news today oh boy
About a lucky man who made the grade
```

after running the script the "out.txt" looks like that:

```
I
read
the
news
today
oh
boy
About
a
lucky
man
who
made
the
grade
```

is anyone can tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the difference between the two lines?

Comment: it prints each word in new line instead of print each line in new line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For per-line input you should use `while read`, for example:

```
cat song.txt | while read line
do
    echo "$line" >> out.txt
done
```

Better (more efficient really) would be the following method:

```
while read line
do
    echo "$line"
done < song.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: more efficient to do the redirection outside of the while loop: `... | while read line; do echo "$line"; done > out.txt`

Comment: @glenn maybe, can't see much difference for this particular case though

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the `for` command that takes every **word** from the list it is given (in your case, the content of the `song.txt` file), whether the words are separated by spaces or newline characters.

What's misguiding you here, is that your for variable name is `line`. `for` only works with words. Reread your script changing `line` by `word` and it should make sense.

Answer (score 1):

In the for-each-in loop the list that is specified is assumed to be white-space separated. A white-space includes a space, new-line, tab etc. In your case the list is the entire text of the file and hence, the loop runs for every word in the file.